# How does windows ensure that the code inside an executable file does not crash the system?

Tags: windows

I understand that an .exe file contains instructions for the processor (opcode?). Now when I run the exe file, windows looks at the file and allocates memory for the process and so on and then...

Does windows just instruct the processor to start executing the code in that file? Then how does windows ensure that the code does not crash the system ( e.g. overwrite a part of RAM where windows is )

or

Does windows somehow parse the exe file and check for 'unsafe' code and then give it to the processor to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern operating systems, Windows included, usually operate in two modes - kernel mode and user mode. In kernel mode you can find the OS kernel, the hardware drivers, and other low level code. User applications run in user mode, where the OS provides your user process with a virtual address space. The user process has no way of reading/writing the kernel address space from user mode, so that's why you can't crash Windows from your user program. You used to be able to, actually. That's what the BSOD in Windows 98 was.

Not to leave you with an oversimplification, you can find out more at this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/user-mode-and-kernel-mode

Edit: it's worth noting that the separation of kernel mode and user mode is supported in the hardware.